# Can anyone tell me how to download whole project in android?

Tags: android

I want to download the whole project from this link:

http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/packages/apps/Contacts/

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: This isn't really an Android question but thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

Or [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for a download manager such as [Flashget](http://www.flashget.com/index_en.html) or so